# Expected top level property 'installed' or 'web' to be present. google-apis-ruby quickstart

Tags: ruby, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-ruby-client

I have been attempting to get device information using the google/apis/admin_directory_v1 api.

I found a ruby quickstart that happens to use this exact api in the example. However when I follow the instructions and try to run the script that is listed in the link I get the error ...

```
"Expected top level property 'installed' or 'web' to be present."
```

A link to the quickstart is below.
EDITED SORRY I WAS OVER TIRED LOL
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/quickstart/ruby

[image: Error when running the example script]

I have been trying to return results from the API all day and it has pushed me to write this post. Please don't attack me I am merely trying to help someone else in the future with this because the documentation is very cavernous for something as simple as api requests?

Anyway I have no idea what the error means or how to proceed. I have fixed enough errors with this situation for one night and now I am just hoping to meet someone else who has traveled this road.

Edited: Sorry to post the wrong link I was too tired. I was never using anything related to the sheets link I must have had the tab open for researched and just pasted the wrong link.

Edited Again: I have gotten a bit further but still no success...  Well actually I take that back I am geting a confirmed bearer token back I am just unsure how to use it properly with this api client... The test I am currently working with is below...

```
require "google/apis/admin_directory_v1"
require "googleauth"
require "googleauth/stores/file_token_store"
require "fileutils"

APPLICATION_NAME = "Directory API Ruby Quickstart".freeze
CREDENTIALS_PATH = "credentials.json".freeze
CUSTOMER_ID = "xxxxxxx".freeze

SCOPE = Google::Apis::AdminDirectoryV1::AUTH_ADMIN_DIRECTORY_USER_READONLY

def authorize
  authorizer = Google::Auth::ServiceAccountCredentials.make_creds(
    json_key_io: File.open('credentials.json'),
    scope: SCOPE)
  authorizer.fetch_access_token!
end

# puts authorize

# Initialize the API
service = Google::Apis::AdminDirectoryV1::DirectoryService.new
service.client_options.application_name = APPLICATION_NAME
service.authorization = Google::Auth.get_application_default(SCOPE)

response = service.list_mobile_devices(customer_id: CUSTOMER_ID)
puts response.to_json
```

This is returning the error below

```
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/google-apis-core-0.4.2/lib/google/apis/core/http_command.rb:229:in `check_status': PERMISSION_DENIED: Request had insufficient authentication scopes. (Google::Apis::ClientError)
```

I would assume that this should be possible with a service account and that I am still making a simple mistake....

Comment: You understand that is a quickstart for google sheets right and not admin directory.

Comment: Thanks! I was just to tired and made the post last thing after being overly burnt out. The link that I meant to post was this >> https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/quickstart/ruby

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are having is that the [Ruby quickstart for Google sheets](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/ruby) was designed for use with an installed application.

You are directed to create installed credentials. Here is a video as well [How to create Google Oauth2 installed application credentials.json.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qwqJcyLQSSQ)

> Authorization credentials for a desktop application. To learn how to create credentials for a desktop application, refer to Create credentials.

This error message is telling you that you did not create that type of credentials.    Did you try to create service account credentials maybe?  That wont work with this code.

Comment: I apologize I posted the wrong link. I was working off of this https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/quickstart/ruby

Comment: I did try using an API key with postman initially. This test request returned the error "Expected OAuth2 access token or other authentication credentials that assert a principal."

I am about to test with a service account if possible because my use case does not require user interaction and will be a server application. 

Thank you for taking the time to help explain the error message. I will come back and let you know when I get it working :)